# Defining longitudinal extent for mercator projection on cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, cartopy

I am trying to plot some data that exists as a matrix e.g.temperature. This data is regional, so I do not need a map of the whole globe.

I have:

1. Matrix of data (mxn)
2. vectors defining the latitudes(mx1) and longitudes(nx1)

I would like to plot it using cartopy with a Mercator projection. However, the mercator only allows me to define the min and max lat, but not the min and max lon. This ends up giving me a wide strip of land.

```
Mercator(central_longitude=103.0,min_latitude=gridlat[0],max_latitude=gridlat[-1])
```

How would I go about setting the min and max longitude of the coastal map?
Ultimately, I just want to plot my data out with the country borders overlaid on it like how it looks using ncview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't usually set the extent of the map when choosing the projection, you can set it later with the `set_extent` method of the axes you create. In fact, the default behaviour in cartopy is to fit the extent to the data that are plotted, so what you want should be what happens when you make a plot with a normal Mercator projection. Here is an example of setting the extent explicitly in geographic coordinates:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Mercator projection with dateline in the middle:
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=180))
# Draw coastlines so we know where we are:
ax.coastlines()
# Set the map extent, making sure to specify the correct coordinate system
# for geographical coordinates:
ax.set_extent([90, 270, -40, 40], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why is the projection defined for ax.set_extent ccrs.PlateCaree()? Should it be Mercator instead?

Comment: No, it should be the coordinate system you are providing the numerical extents in. In this case I want to specify the map extent in latitude/longitude coordinates so `PlateCarree` is the appropriate choice. If I used `Mercator` I'd have to specify the extents in native coordinates for the Mercator projection.

Comment: @user2118915 please "accept" the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.